# Wireless charging with metal plate on back of phone: eddy currents wasting energy and heating up?

Tags: induction, shielding

I just got a car mount for my phone which uses a small magnet stuck to the back of my phone. I'm not sure the material, but I'm guessing it's conductive.

My concern is with wirelessly charging my phone.

Finding all of the necessary parameters to calculate the I^2R losses seems more complicated than it's worth. Does anybody know from experience/intuition whether this will cause any issues? I may try wirelessly charging to see if it's slow, or if the plate heats up, but I'm slightly concerned.

Comment: It will affect it yes.  Maybe even make the wireless charging not work at all.  Depends on the positions of the metal (magnet) and your charging antennae internal to your phone.   I don't think it will damage the charger to try it and it definitely won't damage your phone (unless you have one of those Samsungs that can act as a charger... Don't do that...)